# AJAX No entra en success: function() al subir ficheros

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código para subir archivos `.csv` y necesito mostrar una *alerta*, es decir, una *respuesta* cuando entre en la función *succes*, el problema está que nunca entra a la función.

```
$.ajax({       
        data: data,  
        type: "POST",     
        dataType: "json",
        url: "class/query/q_addcargue.php",
        processData: false, 
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data){
            alert("correcto");
        }
    });
```

He usado algunas veces `AJAX` y creo que el problema es por estas tres líneas de código:

```
    processData: false, 
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
```

Sin embargo, al ponerlas en `true` o quitarlas no sirve él envió del fichero en `AJAX`.

Comment: Revisa esta [pregunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5376896/4092887), allí,. el ejemplo tiene la función `error`. Colócala también en tu código; en el `function error (data)` coloca: `console.log(data)`; actualiza tu pregunta con los resultados.

Comment: Y te consta que el archivo o fichero sube íntegro a la carpeta destino?

Comment: ¿A qué es equivalente `data`? En tu pregunta comentas que es un envío de archivos, sin embargo si data es `.sealizeArray()` no enviará ningun fichero, en ese caso sería mejor usar un `FormData`: `new FormData(this)`. Usar `cache` no tiene sentido aquí porque solo sirve en peticiones `GET` o `HEAD`. Si envías información binaria, como es tu caso, `contentType` puede ser `false` o poner la cabecera `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. ¿Ves algún error en consola?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te va un ejemplo de como lo realizo yo:

```
var params = form2js($('#user_form')); //Esta funcion es una modificacion que por dentro trae un serialize form
    params['pg'] = 'GuardaUsuario';

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each($('#file_imagen')[0].files, function (i, file) {
        data.append('filedata', file);
    });

    for (var key in params) {
        data.append(key, params[key]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: UsuarioHandler, //Este es un url de donde llegara la peticion ej. UsuarioHandler.aspx o Usuarios en caso de usar MVC
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            //Guardado!
        },
        error: function () {
            //error!!!
        }
    });
```

El tema esta en que tienes que crear primero un FormData para que puedas enviar archivos y otros parametros.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada utilizar `var data = $('form').serialize();` no funciona con archivos, ese método solo funciona con datos de tipo texto debes utilizar [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) y el formulario debe tener el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` definido. Para poder subir el archivo utilizando jQuery por medio de AJAX, el siguiente es un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```
<form action="class/query/q_addcargue.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" required />
</form>

<script>
$('form').submit(function(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault(); // Evitar que se recargue la pagina
    var data = new FormData(evento.target); // Datos a partir del formulario
    var $form = $(evento.target) // formulario, es buena practica asignar los selectores de jQuery a una variable cuyo nombre comience con $
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.prop('action'),
        method: $form.prop('method'),
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false, // Evita que jQuery defina el encabezado de la petición como `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
        processData: false // Evita que jQuery modifique los datos a enviar
    })
    .done(function(response) {
       alert('Éxito'); // No ocurrió un error
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(textStatus, errorThrown); // Algo fallo
    });
});
</script>
```

Este método tiene la desventaja de no funcionar con navegadores viejos, puedes revisar http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData para ver la compatibilidad

Answer (score -3):

yo tengo algo similar en mi proyecto con algunas variantes

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "class/query/q_addcargue.php",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("correcto");
        }
    });
```

quitando la propiedad `dataType: "json"` para definir que sera por multi-part

Comment: `dataType` establece **[el formato de datos devuelto](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**. No tiene absolutamente nada que ver con el tipo de datos enviado. Fuera de eso, el código que publicaste es el mismo que el de la pregunta. ¿Cómo solucionaría el problema?